# What approach is used here?

Tags: steganography

[Here](http://screencast.com/t/v8NkmfFTR) is an image hidding some information.
I need to discover, what is the hidden text.

[image]

I tried to interpret this as 27 letter alphabet(with space) in columns, tried this with Ceasar cipher.
No meaningfull English word has occured.

Does somebody have an idea what else can I try?

Comment: is it possible it is encoded in trinary?

Comment: As I said. I tried to interpret it as ternary system. That gave me 27 possible values in the columnt. What most probably is English alphabet. Currently I'm trying to bruteforce it with Vigenere cipher, but still no luck. It should be something really simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried interpreting this as a ternary code written in columns, but why not in rows?

It was really quite simple to solve.

Here's the code I used:

```
for n in ['110','012','111','120','112','001','011','012']:
    x = int(n,3) + 64
    if x==64:
        x=32
    print chr(x),
```

and here's the answer:

> LEMONADE

Comment: Still can't beleave it's that easy...